# How to change active navigation bar background color?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used bootstrap and I would like to change the active page background to green but it doesn't work.

```css
.navbar-inverse {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

When I change the background-color in "Inspect Element" it works like a charm. I don't know what to try anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the background-color of active href item? If yes, you can try this:
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on my computer and it works perfectly.

Why it's not working for you is, I'm guessing, because you are linking your CSS **before** Bootstrap in HTML. In order to override Bootstrap's CSS, you need to link your custom CSS **after** Bootstrap.

Eg:

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" ...>
<!-- put your custom css after bootstrap -->
<link href="my-custom-style.css" ...>
```